# Angular HTTP Interceptor that uses a Service

Tags: angular

I'm trying to take advantage of the new HTTP Interceptor functionality in Angular 4.3+. I have the interceptor working just fine. But I want to catch the errors and emit a toast-style notification using `angular2-toaster`. I put all the toast functionality in a service, `ToasterNotificationService`. But when I try to use that service inside the interceptor, things don't work so well.

If I just try to use the `ToasterNotificationService` in the interceptor by initializing it in the constructor, I get an error of `No provider for xxx`. So then if I import the `Injector` from `@angular/core`, initialize that in the constructor, and then try to inject an instance of the `ToasterNotificationService` manually, the request dies. Like, it literally stops and is never sent to the server. Here's an example of my `intercept` function in my interceptor:

```
intercept (req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log(req);
    const toaster = this.injector.get(ToasterNotificationService);


    return next.handle(req)
        .do((ev: HttpEvent<any>) => {
            if (ev instanceof HttpResponse) {
                console.log('ev in the do: ', ev);
            }
        })
        .catch((response: any) => {
            if (response instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                console.log('response in the catch: ', response);
                toaster.error('Unexpected Error', response.error.message);
            }

            return Observable.throw(response);
        });
}
```

When doing this, the `console.log` on line 2 works, but then the request dies. No errors pop up in the console or in my terminal, and the request never hits the server.

If I just comment out the two lines that reference the toaster, the request goes through to the server.

Does anyone have any ideas on what I can do to bypass this problem?

## Edit

Here's the providers section of my `app.module.ts` where I declare these two services:

```
providers: [
    ToasterNotificationService,
    {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: ErrorInterceptorService,
        multi: true,
    }
]
```

I've tried declaring the `ToasterNotificationService` before and after the `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS`

Comment: Did you import the toast service in the same module you did import your interceptor?

Comment: just wanted to make the same question, if you configurated the provider for the toasterservice right, you should have problems to inject with withouth use of the injector

Comment: Sorry, I should have put that section into the original question. See the edit to see how I declared the providers for the `app.module.ts`.

Comment: do you import the toastermodule? if not, could you remove the service from the providers, import the module and try again with the constructor approach in the interceptor? its weird @pjlamb12

Comment: I was not importing the `ToasterModule`, but even trying that out gives me the same result. The request dies and never even makes it to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the error. I was importing the `ToasterService` from `angular2-toaster` and using it in my custom `ToasterNotificationService`, but never declared that in the `providers` for my app. Once doing that, declaring all three services, everything worked as expected again.

Comment: For other stumbling upon this, try to add this decorator to your interceptor `@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {`, it worked for me.