# Usage of a service from angular HttpInterceptor

Tags: angular, singleton, angular-http-interceptors

I am trying to use a singleton service from a HttpInterceptor in order to have an automatic busy loading indicator.

The problem however is that the interceptor works without the service, but not using the service.

I am referencing the service as follows in the constructor of the HttpInterceptor:

```
constructor(private htbs: HttpBusyService) {}
```

In the app module the service and the HttpInterceptor are provided like this:

```
providers: [
    HttpBusyService,
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy},
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true },
    MessageService,
    ConfirmationService,
]
```

The error i am getting is:

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AuthInterceptor: (?).
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:485)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.js:15664)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (compiler.js:15499)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getInjectableMetadata (compiler.js:15479)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata (compiler.js:15839)
    at eval (compiler.js:15750)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata (compiler.js:15710)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:15278)
    at JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:34226)
```

I have no clue where to look. I obviously am doing something wrong, because i saw other interceptors using singletons.
I am using angular 5.1.0-rc.1 but 5.0.0 had the same problem

Any help is much appreciated

Jan

PS1 I have seen [Angular HTTP Interceptor that uses a Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46006203/angular-http-interceptor-that-uses-a-service)? but the answer doesn't help
PS2 I tried rearranging the providers

EDIT: The Interceptor

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpHandler, HttpEvent,     HttpEventType, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpBusyService } from './http-busy.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private htbs: HttpBusyService) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<HttpEventType.Response>> {
  // this.htbs.start();
const authReq = req.clone({
  setHeaders: { 'X-AUTH-TOKEN': sessionStorage.getItem('token') }
});
return next
.handle(authReq)
.do((ev: HttpEvent<any>) => {
  if (ev instanceof HttpResponse) {
    console.log('processing response', ev);
  }
})
.catch(response => {
  // if (response instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
    console.log('Processing http error', response);
  // }

  return Observable.throw(response);
});
  }
}
```

and the busy service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class HttpBusyService {
  public busy = false;
  private count = 0;
  constructor() { }
  public start() {
    this.count++;
    this.busy = true;
  }
  public finish() {
    this.count--;
    if (this.count <= 0) {
      this.count = 0;
      this.busy = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, provide full implemetation code of your interceptor and service.

Comment: You forgot define @Injectable() in AuthInterceptor class!! ;-)

Comment: The solution by JTejedor was indeed the solution. It works fine now. I don't understand why by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot use the [@Injectable() Decorator](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#injectable) to indicate `AuthInterceptor` is an injectable element.

The [Angular Dependency Injection](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection) works like this. You should define any "injectable" component using `@Injectable` and register in `@Component` provider. To increase the understanding you chould read [this](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/17/resolve-service-dependencies-in-angular-2.html).

Finally, in my humble opinion, sometimes, errors in Angular and its associated call stack are a bit tricky to understand and they are small eloquent